# Add numeric values ​to an adding formula on a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make a macro in VBA-Excel that allows me to generate a simple sum (using a + sign) in a specific cell; keeping all the numbers in the formula of the cell. I mean i need that the output formula "hold" the **values/adding formulas** that are in a certain range. The numbers should be added automatically to the + formula. An special restriction is that in the event that there is no number in a cell of the range, the formula should not incorporate "0".

For example The data shown below are to numbers or sums within a Range (A1:A7):

```
A1: 5
A2: 7,5   --> =5+2,5
A3:
A4: 1
A5: 1     --> =3-2
A6:
A7: 5,5
```

- Where A2: =5+2,5 and A5: =3-2. The other terms are just numbers.
- Range of the example = A1:A7
- Formula Output of the macro on B1 (or Cells(1, 2)) **should be:**

  **=5 + 5 + 2,5 + 1 + 3 - 2 + 5,5**   (20)
- The pseudo code should be like:
  for i = 1 to 7 -> Cells(1, 2).FormulaLocal = if Cell(i,1) is a number (or an existing adding formula with values), add to the current formula. if its blank or 0, skip to next i (or row).
- Output: formula "= Value1(5) + formula2(5+2,5) + Skip0Value3() +
  Value4(1) and so on..

I already tried the following code with partially positive results:

```
Sub summanual()
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As String

    For i = 1 To 7
    
    
        If Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then
        y = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(1, 2).FormulaLocal = Cells(1, 2).FormulaLocal & "+" & y
        End If
      
    Next i
    
    If Cells(1, 2) <> 0 Then
    Cells(1, 2).FormulaLocal = "=" & Cells(1, 2).FormulaLocal
    Else
    Cells(1, 2) = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

1. This works only for positives values. Negatives values are added
   like "+-" to the output formula.
2. The output formula only stores the results of the origin cell. Ex:
   A2 is 5+2,5 but it is added like 7,5. It should be split. Same with
   A5.
3. Is fine to declare "y" variable as String in this case?
4. Any other optimization? Maybe there is a completely different
   approach with better and faster result? Just new with vba-excel

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if we could see some sample data and the expected output from said data. That said, if you want to have VBA calculate a value, then you cannot treat it as a string (ex. `1 + -3` will be `-2` and `1 & "+" & -3` will be `1+-3`)

Comment: First time posting here. My bad if I did it wrong, but I think that I wrote the example like you ask for: The A1 to A7  after the first paragraph are the cells values (and formulas when there is a -->) that are on a example sheet. The output is on the B1 like I wrote on the second paragraph  B1 = 20  with formula of B1=5 + 7,5 + 1 + 1 + 5,5. It should be B1= 20 but with formula =5 + 5 + 2,5 + 1 + 3 - 2 + 5,5 . Thanks for your replay

Comment: Please [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71652551/edit) to clarify it.

Comment: I understand what you are trying but have a hard time trying to figure out why! Why do you need a VBA macro to do this for you? Why not just a simple formula like sum for example?

Comment: Yes that would be the easiest for sure, hahah. The context is that I need to add up the daily production stored in large containers. Where each value of the range is equivalent to the liters that each container has. I need the sum to be expressed in values ​​in the formula because the person who reviews the control sheet needs to verify that not one container has an unusual number of liters. So, boss orders and just daily work :( .  Currently there is a production sheet per day, and it is used to extract the data to a master control sheet (which finally must have the "manual adding formula")